# Getting Input and exiting do while loop in C

Tags: c, string, input, do-while, exit

I'm doing an exercise where i ask the user for an input and then i cypher de input.
Bellow the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char string[50], cypher[50];
int num, i;

do {
    printf("Enter text to cypher: \n");
    scanf(" %s", string);

    do {
        printf("Enter cypher number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &num);

        while (num > 25) // only 25 letters, get number between >25
        {
            num -= 25;
        }
    } while (num <= 0);

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cypher[i] = string[i] + num;
        if (cypher[i] > 90 && cypher[i] < 97) // upper case
        {
            cypher[i] = cypher[i] - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
        }
        if (cypher[i] > 122) //lower case
        {
            cypher[i] = cypher[i] - 'z' + 'a' - 1;

        }

    }
    cypher[i] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", cypher);
}    
 while (string[0] != '0');
```

}

I want to exit the do while loop if the user input is '0' when asked to "Enter text to cypher: " without showing the next menssage "Enter cypher number".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `if (num == 0) break` or change the condition to `while (num < 0)`.

Comment: OT: You need to check the result of `scanf`. To handle the case that a non-number is entered as that can cause an infinete loop with the code as shown.

Comment: Rather than looping and decrementing, just do `num = num % 25` or `num %= 25` (You'll still need to check < 0 unless you like the behavior of % with negative numbers)

Comment: @kaylum but I want to exit the loop in the first input, after "Enter text to cypher" and before "Enter cypher number:" without the later been displayed.

Answer (score 0):

after first scanf you should write something like `if(string[0] == '0') break;`

Comment: Please add why he or she should add that line. Thank you!

Comment: This line will break the big do-while loop without writing the "Enter cypher number: ".

Comment: I had thought about it but is it possible to exit the first do while condition with some condition in the "while"?